# Fast variable-length stack allocator for vector<> in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, vectors

I wrote a variable-length stack allocator for the `vector<>` class in C++ 11. In order to be able to allocate size dynamically at runtime I made use of the non-standard `alloca()` function, which is available in a multitude of C++ implementations, including GCC and Visual Studio.

The purpose of this class is to improve performance of allocation of small arrays on the stack whose size cannot be determined at compile-time while still retaining the helpful features of the `vector<>` class.

```
#pragma once

#include <functional>

template <typename T>
class stack_allocator {
    template<typename> friend class stack_allocator;

public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    typedef T value_type;

    template<typename T2>
    struct rebind {
        typedef stack_allocator<T2> other;
    };

private:
    T* ptr;
    size_t currentSize, maxSize;

public:
    stack_allocator() noexcept :
        ptr(nullptr),
        currentSize(0),
        maxSize(0) {
    }

    stack_allocator(T* buffer, size_t size) noexcept :
        ptr(buffer),
        currentSize(0),
        maxSize(size) {
    }

    template <typename T2>
    explicit stack_allocator(const stack_allocator<T2>& other) noexcept :
        ptr(reinterpret_cast<T*>(other.ptr)),
        currentSize(other.currentSize),
        maxSize(other.maxSize) {
    }

    T* allocate(size_t n, const void* hint = nullptr) {
        T* pointer = ptr + currentSize;
        currentSize += n;
        return pointer;
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, size_t n) {
        currentSize -= n;
    }

    size_t capacity() const noexcept {
        return maxSize;
    }

    size_t max_size() const noexcept {
        return maxSize;
    }

    T* address(T& x) const noexcept {
        return &x;
    }

    const T* address(const T& x) const noexcept {
        return &x;
    }

    T* buffer() const noexcept {
        return ptr;
    }

    template <typename T2>
    stack_allocator& operator=(const stack_allocator<T2>& alloc) {
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void construct(T* p, Args&&... args) {
        new (p) T(forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void destroy(T* p) {
        p->~T();
    }

    template <typename T2>
    bool operator==(const stack_allocator<T2>& other) const noexcept {
        return ptr == other.ptr;
    }

    template <typename T2>
    bool operator!=(const stack_allocator<T2>& other) const noexcept {
        return ptr != other.ptr;
    }
};

#define init_stack_vector(Type, Name, Size) std::vector<Type, std::stack_allocator<Type>> Name((std::stack_allocator<Type>(reinterpret_cast<Type*>(alloca(Size * sizeof(Type))), Size))); Name.reserve(Size)
```

A simple usage example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "stack_allocator.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    cout << "How many integers shall we store? ";
    getline(cin, input);

    init_stack_vector(int, v, stoi(input));
    for (int i = v.capacity() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        v.push_back(i);
    for (int i = v.capacity() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        printf("%d\n", i);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The `init_stack_vector()` macro cannot be substituted by a template function, as that would risk the function not being inlined in Debug mode, and if it's not inlined, `alloca()` would allocate on its stack and it would be popped immediately returning, causing usage of the pointer returned by `alloca()` to depend on undefined behaviour.

Any thoughts/critique?

The completed code can now be found at: https://github.com/mathusummut/StackVector.

*Disclaimer: Never use very large array sizes on the stack in general. Like you should not use `int var[9999999]`, you should similarly not use `new_stack_vector(int, vec, 9999999)`! Use responsibly.*

Comment: You say this is mainly for allocating small vectors.  What's wrong with `vector<int> v(stoi(input),0);`?

Comment: `vector<int> v(stoi(input),0);` is allocated on the heap with is allocated on the heap and is zero-initialized, both of which incur an overhead.

Comment: May be `*p = T(args...);` should've been placement new?

Comment: Ah, you're right! Lemme fix it...

Comment: Seems like due to strongly typed pointer, memory alignment issue is waived. I apologize for worrying about that so much. I would also recommend having a look at [this video](https://youtu.be/LIb3L4vKZ7U?list=FLRtlVv6sNM9iXtgnsYnM8PA), which has recipes for some more sophisticated and interesting allocators. And with `std::memory_resource` it will be possible to implement most of the allocators mentioned in the video.

Comment: I appreciate the concern, that's why I posted the code on Code Review, in order to hopefully get some perspective on things that I may have unknowingly skimmed over. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well this is going to cause problems:

```
void deallocate(T* p, size_t n) {
    currentSize -= n;
}
```

You can't assume that the last allocated object is the one that is de-allocated (I would even say that will never happen).

As a result your next call to allocate is going to re-use that memory even though it is already being used.

```
T* allocate(size_t n, const void* hint = nullptr) {
    T* pointer = ptr + currentSize;
    currentSize += n;
    return pointer;
}
```

Your allocator assumes that its memory is allocated with `alloca()`. But the interface allows any memory to be injected so it has a high likely hood that it is going to be used incorrectly and leak memory. If you are assuming that the memory is going to be free'ed dynamically like that then you need to design the allocator to allocate the appropriate memory.

Also relying on this kind of low level functions is dangerous. What happens when the vector is part of an object? What if the object that holds it is dynamically allocated? There are too many flaws in this design for it be used anywhere apart from your one small use case senario and even then it will need to be well documented to make sure that a future maintainer does not break it.

Comment: I tested whether the assertions made above actually hold true using the following test code: http://pastebin.com/Y9C1tXUh, but the test results were all correct as expected. This is probably due to the `Name.reserve(Size)` statement in the init_stack_vector() macro.

Comment: @MathuSumMut: Not sure that test proves anything. You are testing the state after the object has been resized. The problem will occur during a re-size. But you are probably correct in the it will not happen if your first action is to reserve the maximum space available and never force re-allocation (Which sort of wastes all the work in your allocator you may as well simplify it to the point where it does no work).  Sure it will work for your use case but that does not change its brittleness thus making it not very suitable for general coding or re-use and a definite headache for maintainers.

Comment: Indeed, flexibility has definitely been traded-off for speed of execution. I only intend to use it for personal projects where I want to make use of vector features such as insert while still pretty much retaining the allocation speed of stack arrays. :)

Comment: @MathuSumMut: Given that you can only resize the once. I don't think you will gain any speed. This kind of optimization for speed is only useful if you are doing it billions of times. Since you only do it once  I don't believe this code gains you anything; apart from brittle code.

Comment: Of course, that goes without saying. I wrote a simple benchmark, and the stack-allocated vector of 128 integers was approximately 7 times faster to allocate than 128 integers on the heap. The benefits are significant given the right circumstances.

Comment: 7 nano seconds to 1 nano second is an insignificant speed up. So saying it is 7 times faster is a false measurement. To make a comparison you need the actual times it takes. Then we also need the context it is being used in. If you have written bad code then sure you can optimize the bad code it is still bad and could be faster if just written properly (like hiking the vector out of nested loops and simply resetting). Without further context we really can't say anything constructive apart from the code above is brittle and unlikely to be useful in most contexts.

Comment: I sense your unnecessary mistrust towards my ability to code. What I'd like to remind you is that *an optimisation is an optimisation*. There is no point in writing slower code (even by a slight margin) for no reason. With all due respect, I get that you're trying to warn me of any dangers that may ensue, but rest assured that I more aware of all implementation details than you may realise. There is no reason to coddle myself with slower code for the sake of a needless false sense of security. :)

Comment: I have to disagree with the comment that *"there is no point in writing slower code"* - it does depend on whether the cost outweighs the benefit.  If you double the speed of 1% of your program, when you could have been taking 10% off the execution time of 10% of your program, you've only made half the performance gain you could have done.  And as well as opportunity cost, we have to consider the maintenance cost - time spent fixing bugs or understanding non-obvious code is clearly not time spent contributing to improvements.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to hide something this dangerous in a macro, you should use upper case for its name to highlight the problems.

Do you know what counts as "small enough" for `alloca()`?  On every platform?  On GNU systems, the man page says:

> If the allocation causes stack overflow, program behavior is undefined.

and:

> The inlined code often consists of a single instruction adjusting the stack pointer, and does not check for stack overflow.  Thus, there is no NULL error return.

This means that there is *no* recovery from allocation failure.

What happens when you add more elements to the vector than the reserved size?

Rather than mislead future coders, it would be more honest to use a bare `alloc()` and manage it as an array using pointer and size variables.

Comment: How is it "misleading"? Allocating on the stack always suffers from the same dangers, even when using plain C stack arrays. Why would a C++ newbie even think about custom allocators for `vector`?

Comment: Where has the newbie come from?  Are you expecting `init_stack_vector` to be used by developers who don't understand what it's doing, and why such vectors can't be extended beyond their original capacity?  Even more reason to avoid it, IMO.

Comment: Actually what I mean was that I expect `init_stack_vector` to be used *exclusively* by non-newbie C++ developers, because why would a newbie even consider custom allocators?